# how to get Array inside another array data in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is my FIRESTOREJSON data

[image: This is my Json data]

this is my Code

```
ngOnInit({
   this.itemslist=this.firebaseservice.getOrdersItems();
   this.itemslist.subscribe((user)=>{
       this.userlist=user;
       this.dataSource=newMatTableDataSource(this.userlist);
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;console.log(user);
   })
})
```

**I want to show the data Customer name, mobile number, email address, etc are in Display in the one Table and WASHITEMLIST [ARRAY] data is to display another in another table**
**Actually I want to show this WashItemList data inside MODAL TABLE when I click a particular  table row data**

Comment: Check `this.userlist.WashItemList` after you assign `this.userlist=user;`. You can map this data and use it for your purpose

Comment: Just so I'm sure what you're asking: You have many users who all have WashItemList-arrays. Do you want to show a union of all the users' WashItemList rows? Or do you want to show a table with both user data (CustomerName etc) and WashItemList? How do you want it to be presented?

Comment: I want to show  a table that will show the data of customer name, delivery address, and remaining data but in washItemlist column, I am showing the length of WASHITEMLIST

Comment: @AsimUddin I think I understand. Then you should add a `(click)` handler in your HTML template to the `<tr>` tag. It should call a function that opens the modal and sets the data source of that table.